# FileSystemWatcher not firing created events in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Why does my `FileSystemWatcher` doesn't fire created event but changed events are fired. when i create a new file like usual way, `RightClick` - `New Text Document`, and it doesn't fire. even if i open the file(do nothing) and close it. I think it should be fired because of the `LastAccess`?

```
Public watchfolder As New FileSystemWatcher

Sub FileLogs()
        watchfolder = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher()

        Dim src As String = Form2.TextBox1.Text

        watchfolder.Path = src
        watchfolder.IncludeSubdirectories = True

        watchfolder.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
        watchfolder.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName Or IO.NotifyFilters.FileName
        watchfolder.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Size Or IO.NotifyFilters.Size
        watchfolder.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess Or IO.NotifyFilters.LastAccess
        watchfolder.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite Or IO.NotifyFilters.LastWrite

        AddHandler watchfolder.Changed, AddressOf logattrichanged
        AddHandler watchfolder.Created, AddressOf logcreate

        'Start watching for renames of folders and files
        watchfolder.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub logcreate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    MsgBox(e.Name)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are replacing the NotifyFilter property at every line until you end with the last line that sets only LastWrite. Insted you should Or the previous value with the new one like this

```
watchfolder.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
watchfolder.NotifyFilter = watchFolder.NotifyFilter Or IO.NotifyFilters.FileName
watchfolder.NotifyFilter = watchFolder.NotifyFilter Or IO.NotifyFilters.Size
watchfolder.NotifyFilter = watchFolder.NotifyFilter Or IO.NotifyFilters.LastAccess
watchfolder.NotifyFilter = watchFolder.NotifyFilter Or IO.NotifyFilters.LastWrite
```